# Show equality for momentum operator of dirac field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation

The momentum operator of the dirac field is given by
\begin{align}
P^\mu = \int d^3x:\Psi^\dagger\partial^\mu\Psi:
\end{align}
where,
\begin{align}
\Psi(x) = \int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3\sqrt{2E_p}}\sum_s(a_s(p)u^s(p)e^{-ipx}+b^\dagger_s(p)v^s(p)e^{ipx}) \\
\Psi^\dagger(x) = \int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3\sqrt{2E_p}}\sum_s(a^\dagger_s(p)u^{\dagger s}(p)e^{ipx}+b_s(p)v^{\dagger s}(p)e^{-ipx})
\end{align}

I try to show, that
\begin{align}
P^\mu = \int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3\sqrt{2E_p}} p^\mu\sum_s(a^\dagger_s(p)a_s(p)+b^\dagger_s(p)b_s(p))
\end{align}

When I use $\Psi, \Psi^\dagger$ in the definition for $P^\mu$ above, after calculating the partial derivative I come up with

\begin{align}
P^\mu = \int d^3x\int\frac{d^3p \ \ d^3q}{(2\pi)^62\sqrt{E_pE_q}}:[ \sum_r(a^\dagger_r(q)u^{\dagger r}(q)e^{iqx}+b_r(q)v^r(q)e^{-iqx})\sum_s(a_s(p)u^s(p)e^{-ipx}+b^{\dagger}_s(p)v^s(p)e^{ipx})]:
\end{align}
My problem is, that I dont know how to simplify the product of the two sums in the integral. I know, that
\begin{align}
u^{\dagger r}(p)u^s(p) = 2E_p\delta^{rs} \qquad \text{(same for $v^s(p)$)}
\end{align}
but that is not enough, since $p\neq q$. I think I am missing a relation between the $u(p),v(q)$ but I cant figure it out.

Comment: Hint: you can integrate over x first of all

Comment: Oh boy I was so focused on the momentum itegrals that i didnt notice that.